# django_filters filter_overrides not applying to CharFields with choices

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-filter

I have declared a django_filters.FilterSet with a Meta class where I would like to use filter_overrides in order to customise some of the filters. I am using code very similar to the example in [the official documentation](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filterset.html#customise-filter-generation-with-filter-overrides):

```
class AccommodationFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = AccommodationOffer
        fields = ['numberOfPeople', 'petsAllowed', 'typeOfResidence', 'startDateAccommodation' ]
        filter_overrides = {
            models.BooleanField: {
                'filter_class': django_filters.BooleanFilter,
                'extra': lambda f: {
                    'widget': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'value' : 'true'}),
                },
            },
            models.CharField: {
                'filter_class': django_filters.ChoiceFilter,
                'extra': lambda f: {
                    'widget': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
                },
            },
        }
```

The BooleanFields are showing up as expected, however no matter what I try, the CharFields (which have choices set) do not render with the class="form-control" attribute.

Comment: Ok so this seems to be a bug within django_filters which is specific to fields which have choices set. Someone else has already identified the problem and opened [a PR on the django_filters GitHub](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/pull/1476), but so far this hasn't been intgrated...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned per comment this is a bug within django_filters. As long as [this issue](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/issues/1475) doesn't get resolved one would have to modify the django_filters code.

In case anyone walks into the same problem this is the workaround I came up with:

```
class MyFilterSet(django_filters.FilterSet):

    [...]
    
    def __init__(self, data=None, queryset=None, *, request=None, prefix=None):
        super().__init__(data, queryset, request=request, prefix=prefix)
        for f in self.filters.values():
            if isinstance(f, django_filters.ChoiceFilter):
                    f.extra.update({'widget': forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'})})
```